# Python syntax for IF/THEN Compared to PHP

Tags: php, python, syntax, if-statement

I have a this code in PHP:

```
 if($id = $this->ci->srr->check_faca_indiv($name))
{
    return $id;
} elseif($id = $this->_addIndiv($name)) {
    return $id;
} else {
    return null;
```

I use this basic structure all over the place and it may not be great, but it's what I'm used to. The functions basically try to do some simple operations and if they fail they return a null value. I tried to mimic that in porting it over to Python, but got syntax errors and ended up modifying it to this:

```
indiv_id = checkIndiv(name)
if indiv_id != None:
    return indiv_id
indiv_id = addIndiv(name)
if indiv_id != None:
    return indiv_id
else:
    return None
```

I think that gets me to the same place but I don't like it as much -- is there a way more similar to PHP that I'm missing?

Comment: use `if indiv_id is not None:` or even more succinctly `if indiv_id:`

Comment: is this whole thing intended to be some kind of `get_or_create()`?

Comment: I'm with fingerman, you should have found elif first.

Comment: @fingerman: how would elif help in this case?

Comment: D'oh -- can't believe I don't have elif in there. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

something like:

```
return checkIndiv(name) or addIndiv(name)
```

Comment: short maybe, but readable? neither checkIndiv nor addIndiv seem to do what their names advertise.

Comment: what do the functions do? I didn't write or name them. The OP asked for a simpler way.

Comment: Thanks so much.  I wasn't aware of this syntax in Python and am now using it all the functions.  The functions are a bit messy -- basically they check to see if a certain record is already entered into the db and if not then they add it.  In both cases they return an id of the record.

Answer (score 2):

The basic problem with your code is that the final branch serves no purpose. Even in your PHP example it basically says:

```
if (null) return null;
```

You can reduce everything to:

```
indiv_id = checkIndiv(name)
if indiv_id:
    return indiv_id
else:
    return addIndiv(name)
```

(If indiv_id could become something that compares to `False`, you should check against `None`, but use `is` instead of `==`!)

Maybe you could work with exceptions:

```
def check_or_add(name):
    try:
        return checkIndiv(name)
    except CheckException:
        return addIndiv(name)
```

On the whole, though, your semantics strike me as odd: I would not expect a function with "check" in the name to return an object instead of simply `True` or `False`. I'd probably use different names:

```
id = get_indiv(name)
if id:
    return id
else:
    return new_indiv(name)
```

That makes James' solution more readable as well:

```
return get_indiv(name) or new_indiv(name)
```

Comment: Your answer was extremely helpful and I actually used it to answer another problem I was having.  Now if you want me to post that question for you...

Comment: @tchaymore: nah, I'm just glad I could help.